# Front end and Back end Folder are missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have install Spree ecommerce following this link
https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html

all are work but canot find out the backend and frontend folder. 
Can anyone teach me how to show or find out all the controller in Back end and front end

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: What do you mean with the backend/frontend folder?  Spree is rails based and has the standard rails directory structure. Rails in total is the "backend", but it renders the `views` which are shown on the frontend. Also, to add to the confusion: in the spree documentation they use the "backend" as referring to the administration part, and "frontend" referring to your actual store.

Comment: I cannot found the folder /shop_app/backend/app/controller/...............  and  /shop_app/frontend/app/controller/.............. but at localhost3000: still can run. because i wan to customize the file

Comment: you can copy it from [github](https://github.com/spree/spree), if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spree 3.4 you can copy views (turned on by default).

```
rails g spree:install --migrate=false --sample=false --seed=false --copy_views=false
```

If you have an older version then you have to copy views from GitHub Spree repo.